# CriteriaQuery to count children of an entity produces malformed numeric constant: . error

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria, criteria-api

I have the following tables in the database. All expressed with Hibernate annotations in my Java code.

```
|LibraryItem Table             |
|LibraryItemId|LibraryItemTitle|

|ItemListing Table                              |
|ListingId|ChildLibrayItemId|ParentLibraryItemId|
```

So basically there are library items. And each library item may be a child or a parent of another library item and this relationships are stored in the Itemlisting table.

I am trying to get the count of all the children of a particular library item using the CriteriaBuilder approach. Here's my code:

```
public int getNumChildren(LibraryItem libItem) {
        CriteriaBuilder builder = sessionFactory.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Long> query = builder.createQuery(Long.class);
        Root<LibraryItem> root = query.from(LibraryItem.class);
        query.select(builder.count(root.get("itemChildren")));
        query.where(builder.equal(root.get("libraryItemId"), libItem.getLibraryItemId()));
        return Math.toIntExact(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(query).uniqueResult());
    }
```

this produces the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: malformed numeric constant: . in statement [select count(.) as col_0_0_ from library_item libraryite0_, ITEM_LISTING itemchildr1_, library_item libraryite2_ where libraryite0_.LIBRARY_ITEM_ID=itemchildr1_.PARENT_LIB_ITEM_ID and itemchildr1_.CHILD_LIB_ITEM_ID=libraryite2_.LIBRARY_ITEM_ID and libraryite0_.LIBRARY_ITEM_ID=4601]
```

Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong here please?

EDIT:

Here's the entity class. I've omitted some of the code that I think is irrelevant:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "library_item", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"LIBRARY_ITEM_TITLE", "LIBRARY_ID"})

})
public class LibraryItem extends DatabaseObject {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "hilo_sequence_generator")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "hilo_sequence_generator",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
            parameters = {
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "hilo_seqeunce"),
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "1"),
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "100"),
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "optimizer", value = "hilo")
            })
    @Id
    @Column(name = "LIBRARY_ITEM_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long libraryItemId;

    @Column(name = "LIBRARY_ITEM_TITLE", nullable = false)
    private String libraryItemTitle;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "ITEM_LISTING",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_LIB_ITEM_ID", nullable=false)},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="CHILD_LIB_ITEM_ID", nullable = false)})
    private Set<LibraryItem> itemChildren = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "itemChildren")
    private Set<LibraryItem> itemParents = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Comment: Can you show your entity classes also?

Comment: `root.get("itemChildren")` is a multi-valued field by any chance?because it shouldn't be, for use with COUNT, as per the JPA spec

Comment: Added the entity class. And no, pretty sure it's not a multi valued field, in fact It's not a field but a relationship.

Comment: A Set (`private Set<LibraryItem> itemChildren`) is a MULTI VALUED FIELD. It has multiple values! A relation FIELD is still a FIELD. You cant do COUNT of that. You can use the JPA function SIZE on it,

Comment: why your JPA provider doesn't flag that up as an error when you call it is another question; should never leave it to executing SQL just to expect a user to have to debug backwards wtf was wrong. Raise a bug on it

Comment: @DN1, yes you're right! Didn't really know what a MULTI VALUED FIELD was and googling it didn't help. Using size instead of count did in fact make the query work. You should add the comment as an answer and I'll select/upvote it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `count` on a multi-valued field. This is invalid in JPQL, and hence also in Criteria.

The way to do that would be to make use of the `size` function ([`CriteriaBuilder.size`](http://www.datanucleus.org/javadocs/javax.persistence/2.2/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#size-javax.persistence.criteria.Expression-)), which is explicitly for collection fields.